# Accessing secure FTP server files

Tags: python, curl, ftp, adobe-analytics

I am trying to connect to the omniture ftp host: ftp://ftp.omniture.com/ with a username and password. I am able to do this and access the files through the browser but connection through curl and wget times out:

```
curl ftp://myftpsite.com/a_file.zip --user myname:mypassword -o a_file.zip
```

Also trying to connect through the python library "ftplib" fails:

```
[Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

I want to programatically access files on this server. How can I do this?

I am trying not to install any other library. I do not have access and the process might delay things.

Comment: What does using `curl` with the verbose option show, _i.e._: `curl -v ftp://ftp.omniture.com --user myname:mypassword -o a_file.zip` show?

Comment: % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* About to connect() to ftp.omniture.com port 21 (#0)
*   Trying XX.XXX.XXX.XX...
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:02:07 --:--:--     0* Connection timed out
* Failed connect to ftp.omniture.com:21; Connection timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed connect to ftp.omniture.com:21; Connection timed out

Comment: Hrm.  Attempting to just do `curl -v ftp://ftp.omniture.com` works here, in terms of _connecting_.  `curl`'s default anonymous login fails, as expected.  If even the above fails for you (_i.e._ no `-o` option), it suggests that your client machine can't resolve "ftp.omniture.com" to an IP address (here it resolves to 66.235.132.90), or otherwise doesn't have network/routing access to that IP address or port.  That's what the "Connection timed out" message suggests to me.

Comment: you are right! the development machine did not have access.